# How to Test platform Event Trigger Flow

Tags: unit-test, visual-workflow, platform-event

I have a flow which subscribes to a platform Event. This flow consumes the event and inserts a record.
My test class is:

```
Test.startTest();
            
Database.SaveResult result = EventBus.publish(testEvent);
System.assertEquals(true, result.isSuccess());  
Test.getEventBus().deliver();

Test.stopTest();
```

It looks like only Apex triggers are running after the Test.getEventBus().deliver() statement while Flow is not at all getting triggered. I thoroughly  checked the logs and there is no logs of the Flow running. I checked that the Flow is Active.
Salesforce explicitly says that flows are triggered from apex test class here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_test_events.htm

Comment: What API version is your test class using? The documentation mentions that the test class needs to be v43.0 or newer for processes/flows to be run.

Comment: My Test class is at API version: v52.0

Comment: I have checked that this works for both standard and custom events and with both publish after commit and publish immediate . The only requirement seems to be that the flow must be active. Can you confirm that flow is active?

Comment: Yes. The flow is active. The event is setup as publish immediately.  This seems to be the case for all the platform event flows in my org. Any other suggestion?

Comment: This will need checking your org. Please consider logging a case with salesforce support for further investigation on this.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query to check the flow is subscribed to the platform event.

`SELECT Name, Position, Retries, LastError  FROM EventBusSubscriber`

If its not listed, save a new version of the flow.
I ran into this on a newly created sandbox